# Is it possible to edit dark UI theme colours in Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

Is it possible to get rid of the bluish tint in the dark interface theme of Spyder 4.1?
How can I do it, if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, that's not possible.